How to recover exFAT formatted CFExpress Card? Mistakenly corrupted files by Apple Photos and I overwritten files on it
I'm an amateur videographer and bought a Fujifilm XH2 camera and Angelbird CFExpress MK2 card with it. I didn't buy card reader at first.
The situation occurred as follows:
I've shot several solo performer musicians.
That day I tried to copy the clips via USB-C / Apple Photos. I didn't know that this app has 4gb of data limitation while transferring. So I transferred almost 25GB of data which has to be 300GB. Photos.app corrupts files after 4gb. 5min of clips with 4K ProRes422 codec would be around ~50GB. I got 4GB of files everywhere after import. I thought it was a codec error after I try to preview the files but I couldn't see nothing after 15 sec of each clip. It was just black.
I deleted the old clips that also I thought I have the clips It's just a codec problem and deleted all of them.
I did this loop 3 times with 20 musicians. Each clip around ~5 to ~8 minutes. I bought a cheap CFExpress reader card and realized with the moment of truth.
Despite my stupidity, How can I scan/recover files by scanning the card sector-by-sector / byte-to-byte ?
I tried , Tensorshare, DiskDrill, Recuva, DMDE, Treasured.
Only Treasured found some other could not find.
What should I do to recover these clips?

You've already tried various tools. It is likely you're out of luck. From your comment on the deleted answer, you have already overwritten the data. You may consider paying significant fees to reputable data recovery services, but because you've overwritten the data, there is no promise you'll get a good copy back from even that level of expertise and cost.

Does this answer your question? Recover data from SD card

Hi @JoepvanSteen, I didn't accept an answer. Anyways, there are multiple tools to recover and whatever the current condition is doesn't matter actually. They are all write on disk while recovering. I found a guys called "Treasured". They found the files while others cannot. I tried all of them. The best one I have tried called UFSExplorer. At the end of the day, They see an opportunity and overcharged me and I decided to reshoot the takes.
